# XCUITest - How to check if webview has updated its content?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xctest, xcuitest

I've got a webview that changes it's content when a button is pressed inside the webview. Is it possible to detect if webview has changed its content in XCUITest.

Edit: I would like a general way to know if the webview has updated without having to know the content the webview will update to–prior to the update.

Answer (score 0):

Sure !

You can get your webview doing something like this:

```
let webview = app.webViews.firstMatch
```

Then, you can do some assertions on the webview content:

```
webview.staticTexts["TestString"].firstMatch.exists
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. This assumes you know what the content will be prior to the webview updating. Do you know if theres a general way to know if the webview has updated without knowing the new content?

Comment: Hum, you can try to update its accessibility identifier each time the webview is updated.